# Arduino Serial.write to Processing returning 0?

Tags: events, serialization, arduino, processing, communication

I've currently got an Arduino program communicating accelerometer values via a Serial event to processing working perfectly. I'm trying to add a thermometer to my setup however processing is only receiving 0 from reading the pin. If I Serial.print the reading in setup it does print to the serial monitor just fine, however I can't get it to send proper values alongside my accelerometer readings.

Arduino code:

```
int inByte = 0;

void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  establishContact();  // send a byte to establish contact until receiver responds
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    // get incoming byte:
    inByte = Serial.read();

    // send sensor values:
    Serial.write(analogRead(A3)); // X AXIS
    Serial.write(analogRead(A2)); // Y AXIS
    Serial.write(analogRead(A1)); // Z AXIS
    Serial.write(analogRead(A0)); // TEMPERATURE
  }
}

void establishContact() {
  while (Serial.available() <= 0) {
    Serial.print('A');   // send a capital A
    delay(300);
  }
}
```

Processing code:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;                       
int[] serialInArray = new int[4];    
int serialCount = 0;                 
int xInput, yInput, zInput;
float temperature;
boolean firstContact = false;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  pixelDensity(2);
  noStroke();
  background(0);
  printArray(Serial.list());
  String portName = Serial.list()[4];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw() {
}

void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
  // read a byte from the serial port:
  int inByte = myPort.read();
  // if this is the first byte received, and it's an A,
  // clear the serial buffer and note that you've
  // had first contact from the microcontroller. 
  // Otherwise, add the incoming byte to the array:
  if (firstContact == false) {
    if (inByte == 'A') { 
      myPort.clear();          // clear the serial port buffer
      firstContact = true;     // you've had first contact from the microcontroller
      myPort.write('A');       // ask for more
    }
  } else {
    // Add the latest byte from the serial port to array:
    serialInArray[serialCount] = inByte;
    serialCount++;

    // If we have 3 bytes:
    if (serialCount > 2 ) {

      zInput = serialInArray[0]-80;
      yInput = serialInArray[1]-80+69;
      xInput = serialInArray[2]-77;
      temperature = serialInArray[3]; // should return voltage reading (i.e 16ºc = 130);
      //println("x = " + xInput + ", y = " + yInput + ", z = " + zInput + ", Temp = " + serialInArray[3]);

      // Send a capital A to request new sensor readings:
      myPort.write('A');
      // Reset serialCount:
      serialCount = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The accelerometer values print perfectly, but temperature just returns a 0. Serial.print(analogRead(A0)) in the serial monitor gives me the correct values, so the thermometer is definitely working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: > // If we have 3 byte ... we don't have the temperature yet ;)

Answer (score 1):

In this line ,

if (serialCount > 2 ) {

change for

if (serialCount >= 4 ) {

OR try to use typecasting or change the temperature for integer !!!

int temperature;

Comment: Thank you! This alongside shifting the length of the array to be slightly larger than the amount of data I was receiving helped! For some strange reason if I pushed the array length to 5 when I only needed 4, temp started reading correctly. Managed to add a photo cell as well, so 5 inputs working nicely. Thank you!

Comment: I do have one problem though, which is that my photo cell sensor is only sending values from 0–255 in processing (arduino serial monitor reads as 700+ when I serial.print) even though I'm using Serial.write to send the photo cell values to processing. Any idea how I can fix this?